# Module not specified after opening project from another computer

Tags: android, android-studio

I keep my projects in my Dropbox folder. I installed Android Studio on my laptop and I tried to open the Project. All java files had a red circle which I managed to fix by marking the Directory as `Sources Root`. When I try to run the application, the `Edit configuration` window pops up with a sign at the bottom saying that `Module is not specified`, in red. There is no module I can select in the appropriate combobox. Syncing project with grandle files has no effect and importing the project instead of opening it makes things even worse. At the Projects side tab, by selecting the `Android` option, I can only see the `Grandle Scripts` structure and not the project files. The project files are visible when I select the `Project` option from the combobox.

The project cannot even open at the original computer anymore. I am new to Android and I have spent a lot of time developing this project. What can I do to reverse the situation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change some gradle properties.

First you open android studio and create a new project. Then change your old project's all gradle properties according to new project. like bellow--

1. Go to your build.gradle(Module:app) script and change the gradle version like `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` to your current version.
2. Go to your build.gradle(Project:your app) script change this line `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'` to your current version.
3. Finally you have to change gradle-wrapper.properties(Gradle Version) `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`
    to your current version

Now sync your project, I hope it will working fine.

Comment: Thank you. I finally managed to fix it. I searched in Dropbox file history which of the configuration files had changed and tried to see the actual changes. I found out that in ".idea" folder file named grandle.xml, the  property <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/app" /> was changed into <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/app" />. I switched back and everything works as it should.